# Why is Winforms template missing from my .NET 7?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I have a Linux laptop and there is already installed .NET. This is result of `dotnet --list-sdks` command line:

```
5.0.404 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.404 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

and I have *global.json* file in my CWD like this:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.101",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```

But when I am running `dotnet new winforms` command in my terminal I get this response:

> No templates or subcommands found matching: 'winforms'.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: **Win**forms is for **Windows** only and thus **not available** on Mac or Linux

Comment: oh! it was my assumption that Windows form in .Net core enables us to develop desktop applications on all platforms like Java or QT.